# MergeSort java Graphical representation

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Hi I have got merge Sort class I want to plot histogram of sorting array and when try to retrieve data from sorting class on screen appearing only unsorted array and then sorted array. How I have to restructure my sorting class so the full array will be returned on every occurrence of sorting or how I can retrieve merge(array, left, right) (I think this is the part I have to use to create histogram)

```
package mergeSort;


import java.util.*;

public class MergeSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = {14, 32, 67, 76, 23, 41, 58, 85};
        System.out.println("before: " + Arrays.toString(list));
        mergeSort(list);
        System.out.println("after:  " + Arrays.toString(list));
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int[] array) {
        if (array.length > 1) {
            // split array into two halves
            int[] left = leftHalf(array);
            int[] right = rightHalf(array);

            // recursively sort the two halves
            mergeSort(left);
            mergeSort(right);

            // merge the sorted halves into a sorted whole
            merge(array, left, right);
        }
    }

    // Returns the first half of the given array.
    public static int[] leftHalf(int[] array) {
        int size1 = array.length / 2;
        int[] left = new int[size1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
            left[i] = array[i];
        }
        return left;
    }

    // Returns the second half of the given array.
    public static int[] rightHalf(int[] array) {
        int size1 = array.length / 2;
        int size2 = array.length - size1;
        int[] right = new int[size2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
            right[i] = array[i + size1];
        }
        return right;
    }

    public static void merge(int[] result, int[] left, int[] right) {
        int i1 = 0;   // index into left array
        int i2 = 0;   // index into right array

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (i2 >= right.length || (i1 < left.length && 
                    left[i1] <= right[i2])) {
                result[i] = left[i1];    // take from left
                i1++;
            } else {
                result[i] = right[i2];   // take from right
                i2++;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Also when  I call for example bubble sort everything working fine so I think I must restructure the mergeClass 
Please share if you have an idea thank you

This is my printing method

```
int Value = 100;
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int edge= 50;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            g.drawLine(i + offSet, Value + edge, i + edge,
                    Value + edge- array[i]);
        }
    }
```

Bubble sort

```
    public void bubbleSort(int[] a) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (a.length - i); j++) {
            if (a[j - 1] > a[j])
                swap(a, j - 1, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would keeping a record of each step (rather than returning it each step) suffice?  If so the following would give you a List of int[] arrays, each storing the value at each step of the sorting process.  You could then iterate over the list and display it at your leisure.
The following:

```
package mergeSort;


import java.util.*;

public class MergeSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = {14, 32, 67, 76, 23, 41, 58, 85};

        List<int[]> listOfLists = new ArrayList<int[]>();

        System.out.println("before: " + Arrays.toString(list));
        mergeSort(list,listOfLists);
        System.out.println("after:  " + Arrays.toString(list));

        System.out.println("Each step:");
        for(int[] arrList : listOfLists)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrList));
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int[] array, List<int[]> listOfLists) {
        if (array.length > 1) {
            // split array into two halves
            int[] left = leftHalf(array);
            int[] right = rightHalf(array);

            // recursively sort the two halves
            mergeSort(left,listOfLists);
            mergeSort(right,listOfLists);

            // merge the sorted halves into a sorted whole
            merge(array, left, right);
            listOfLists.add(array);

        }
    }

    // Returns the first half of the given array.
    public static int[] leftHalf(int[] array) {
        int size1 = array.length / 2;
        int[] left = new int[size1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
            left[i] = array[i];
        }
        return left;
    }

    // Returns the second half of the given array.
    public static int[] rightHalf(int[] array) {
        int size1 = array.length / 2;
        int size2 = array.length - size1;
        int[] right = new int[size2];
        for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
            right[i] = array[i + size1];
        }
        return right;
    }

    public static void merge(int[] result, int[] left, int[] right) {
        int i1 = 0;   // index into left array
        int i2 = 0;   // index into right array

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (i2 >= right.length || (i1 < left.length && 
                    left[i1] <= right[i2])) {
                result[i] = left[i1];    // take from left
                i1++;
            } else {
                result[i] = right[i2];   // take from right
                i2++;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Would return this:

```
before: [14, 32, 67, 76, 23, 41, 58, 85]
after:  [14, 23, 32, 41, 58, 67, 76, 85]
Each step:
[14, 32]
[67, 76]
[14, 32, 67, 76]
[23, 41]
[58, 85]
[23, 41, 58, 85]
[14, 23, 32, 41, 58, 67, 76, 85]
```

Comment: how can i pass that list to my drawing method

Comment: I don't know how your drawing method works so I can't say.  You could post your drawing method and/or your bubble sort class and maybe I we can figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I understand the problem you have.  Does this work for you?  Where I've put the println statement you can instead render the current array.

```
package mergeSort;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] list = { 14, 32, 76, 67, 41, 23, 58, 85 };

        System.out.println("before: " + Arrays.toString(list));
        mergeSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
        System.out.println("after:  " + Arrays.toString(list));

    }

    public static void mergeSort(int[] array, int left, int right) {
        int mid = 0;

        if (right > left) {
            mid = (right + left) / 2;

            // sort left
            mergeSort(array, left, mid);
            // sort right
            mergeSort(array, mid + 1, right);
            // merge them
            merge(array, left, mid+1, right);

            // PUT YOUR HOOK TO DRAW THE ARRAY HERE
            System.out.println("during: " + Arrays.toString(array));
        }

    }

    public static void merge(int[] numbers, int left, int mid, int right) {
        int[] temp = new int[numbers.length];
        int i, left_end, num_elements, tmp_pos;
        left_end = (mid - 1);
        tmp_pos = left;
        num_elements = (right - left + 1);

        while ((left <= left_end) && (mid <= right)) {
            if (numbers[left] <= numbers[mid])
                temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];
            else
                temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];
        }

        while (left <= left_end)
            temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[left++];

        while (mid <= right)
            temp[tmp_pos++] = numbers[mid++];

        for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++){
            numbers[right] = temp[right];
            right--;
        }
    }

}
```

The output that is produced is this:

```
before: [14, 32, 76, 67, 41, 23, 58, 85]
during: [14, 32, 76, 67, 41, 23, 58, 85]
during: [14, 32, 67, 76, 41, 23, 58, 85]
during: [14, 32, 67, 76, 41, 23, 58, 85]
during: [14, 32, 67, 76, 23, 41, 58, 85]
during: [14, 32, 67, 76, 23, 41, 58, 85]
during: [14, 32, 67, 76, 23, 41, 58, 85]
during: [14, 23, 32, 41, 58, 67, 76, 85]
after:  [14, 23, 32, 41, 58, 67, 76, 85]
```

Comment: no that doesn't work what i was thinking when i will call my method  like mergeSort(array); the method will return the array on every step of sorting i am trying to rewrite sorting method that way if you have any other idea pleas share

Comment: Methods in Java can't return multiple times.  One call to mergeSort(array) will return one (or zero) values.  It can return an array of many values, or an object that stores many values, but it still will return only once.

Comment: please take look at bubble sort above. if you can please explain me how bubble sort animation display sorting process